# Simple phonebook program removing contact

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am making a simple phonebook using text files because I am a beginner and it is homework.  I have the view contacts and add functions correct.  My only issue is i can't figure out how to remove a contact by using input.  I am using vectors.  I have a class to declare my variables and functions.  Here is what I have so far:

I removed the other function as I am only focusing on removing a contact and to reduce confusion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class phonebook
{
public:
void deletecontact();


private://declaring the variables
vector<string> name;//Graves the contact and phone number
string NAME;
string delete_contact;//input to delete contact
bool flag = 0;

};

void phonebook::deletecontact()
{
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

fin.open("phonebook.txt");
fout.open("phonebook.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);


if (fout.fail())
{
    cout << "Error";
    exit(1);
}

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Error";
    exit(1);
}

   while (getline(fin, NAME)){
    name.push_back(NAME);

}


cout << "Type in who you want to delete" << endl;

cin >> delete_contact;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
    if (delete_contact==name[i])
    {
        system("cls");
        flag =1;
    }

    if(flag)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)
        if(name[i].erase(delete_contact))
    {
        cout << "Deleted successfully!" << endl;
        fout << name[i];
    }
    }



fin.close();
fout.close();

system("PAUSE");

}
```

this is my error:

In member function 'void phonebook::deletecontact()':|
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string::erase(std::string&)'|

Criticism would be cool too

Comment: Why all the `flag` variables to remove an item from a vector?   To remove an item from a vector is a two-liner, if that many lines, using `vector::erase() / std::remove_if`.

Comment: Make that a one-liner:  `name.erase(std::remove(name.begin(), name.end(), delete_contact), name.end());`

Comment: I tried using vector::erase, but i dont know how the code would look like using input. Example I dont want myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+3) I want an input to remove it by name. Idk how to do that.

Comment: You forgot the missing piece:  `std::remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you're trying to call `string::erase()` with an argument that is a `std::string`.  There is no such function in the `std::string` class.  The `name[i]` is a `std::string`, so you're attempting to call `erase` on a `std::string`.

What you want to do is call `vector::erase`, and provide the iterator to the item you want to erase.  To do this, you could easily remove the name using the `vector::erase` along with `std::remove`

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
name.erase(std::remove(name.begin(), name.end(), delete_contact), name.end());
```

No need for `flag` variables, no loops, etc.  The `remove` algorithm function returns an iterator to the items that match the name.  Then it's just a matter of erasing all the items starting at this iterator.

Note:

If you only want to remove the first item found (instead of all of the items that match the `delete_contact`), then replace the `std::remove` with `std::find`.

Comment: thanks this made alot of sense right here. I appreciate the help

Comment: its not erasing anything :/  I have removed all loops and flags 

`cout << "Type in who you want to delete" << endl;

      cin >> delete_contact;
    name.erase(std::remove(name.begin(), name.end(), delete_contact), name.end());`

Comment: @RyanWeaver It isn't going to find a name that doesn't exist.  Obviously the `delete_contact` name you are searching for isn't in the vector.

Comment: @RyanWeaver Simple program:  http://ideone.com/sEaoZf  Therefore the conclusion is that the name doesn't exist in the vector.  That is the only conclusion, as the algorithm functions are never "wrong", which is why they are powerful.  More than likely, your "delete_contact" has a stray character in it (like a carriage return or similar unprintable character) or you're just not noticing the difference between what's in your vector and the name you're trying to delete.

Comment: Alright I think I know what my issue is.  What you linked me and the line of code is doing what it's suppose to do.  I took the last two code of lines in your link to show if the contact is being deleted and it is.  The issue I am having is outputting it into the file I have which is "phonebook.txt". and being able to reread it through the compiler with the option i have "View contacts" and all the other contacts are there.  Basically need the output to rewrite the file but with the non deleted contacts.

Comment: Heres my actual program all you need to do is create a text file with a name and a phonenumber or create a text file and compile and use the add contact function pastebin.com/h1nck9V3

You helped a lot though and I appreciate it thanks man if i know how to rate you ill give you  100000/10

Answer (score 1):

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator itr = name.begin(); itr != name.end(); itr++) // Use iterators for looping
{
    if (delete_contact == *itr) // Get the correct iterator 
    {
        system("cls");
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (flag)
{
    if (name[i].erase(itr)) // Erase for the correct iterator
    {
        cout << "Deleted successfully!" << endl;
        fout << name[i];
    }
}
```

This is just to mend what you have. I would use `std::find` and `std::remove` if I was you.